# Arcpy tool attribute selection

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute

I'm trying to make tool of change detection between two polygons layers by fields of initial state and final state. Everything is working except attribute selection, I would like user could choose whether areals with no change include or exclude from calculations. I create new layer by intersection, then I want to compare values in field of initial state with values in field of final state and exclude areals without change.

```
# select areals without no change
if change == "Exclude":
    where_clause = '"' + field_initial + '" <> ' + "'" + field_final + "'"
    arcpy.Select_analysis(output_fc, output_select2, where_clause)
```

output_fc is layer created by intersection.

It creates new layer, but with all objects, it makes no selection at all, I would like to get same result as when I use attribute selection in ArcMAP. I tried to do it in python window, also in tool, there is no error in expression but no selection.

[image]

Comment: What data type are the fields that you are comparing?

Comment: Data type is string, values are codes of category, for example 21310 (string not number) ... it is code of land cover category.

Comment: I think you have your quotes mixed up on the 2nd field in the where clause.  You use single quotes instead of double quotes. Try this:     where_clause = '"' + field_initial + '" <> ' + '"' + field_final + '"'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've swapped usage of quotes in your Python snippet. Instead of passing in a quoted field name, you've supplied a string literal, ie `"KOD5" <> 'KOD5_1'`.

You need to change the quoting so that the second field name is quoted with double quotes instead:

```python
# select areals without no change
if change == "Exclude":
    where_clause = '"' + field_initial + '" <> "' + field_final + '"'
    arcpy.Select_analysis(output_fc, output_select2, where_clause)
```